# Using 'late' as a preposition?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, interpretation, poetry

Second stanza of *The Convergence of the Twain* by Thomas Hardy:

> Steel chambers, **late the pyres**
> Of her salamandrine fires,
> Cold currents thrid, and turn to rhythmic tidal lyres.

Can 'late' be used as a preposition and what does it mean in the above lines?

Comment: Late can be short for lately.

Comment: I take it to refer to the ship's boilers, formerly containing fire but now full of water.

Comment: Good question, Soyuz42! And thanks for pointing out a wonderful poem I had never read. I'm sure Kate Bunting is right: Not long ago they were the boilers.

Comment: The word shown as "third" in the quotation, is "thrid" in the poem, meaning "thread".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Fixed (although it is quoted this way in _Backpack Literature_, the book I'm reading).

Comment: It's often not possible to really apply the "rules" or  principles or aspects of grammar" to poetry.  I read this as @KateBunting does.  However, if I had to assign a part of speech to "late', it would be an adjective and not a preposition.

Comment: It's a well-chosen word. As an adjective it suggests "the late", meaning "the no longer alive". As an abbreviated form of "lately" or "of late" it function more like an adverb, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a preposition. Prepositions are used to indicate relation between two (or more) separate objects; here the pyres and the steel chambers are the same objects (However, "of" is a preposition, showing relationship between the *pyres/steel chambers* and the *fires*, which are separate objects, with the former containing the latter).

I would argue it is an adverb, modifying an omitted and implied verb "were", with "late" being used in a manner equivalent to "formerly" (See adverb definition 3 here: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/late). I'd argue a less poetical equivalent sentence would be:

> Steel chambers, (which were) *formerly* the pyres/ Of her *salamander-like* fires/ *pass through* cold currents, and become rhythmic tidal *musical instruments*